# Cell Style PatternType in EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have been looking for a way to set the PatternType of cells in a column to Diagonal Crosshatch while using EPPlus.

First of all, changing the library is not an option here since the original work is not mine and I wouldn't want to mess it up.

So how do we set the PatternType  to lets say Diagonal Crosshatch or Thin Horizontal Strips Honestly, searched entire internet, and no clue how to do this.

**Sample line of code**, that I have been using:

```
ws.Cells["D1:D" + lastRowNumber].Style.Fill.PatternType=OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Gray125;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change pattern types you would just change the ExcelFillStyle.

For Thin Horizontal Stripes:

```
ws.Cells["D1:D" + lastRowNumber].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.ThinHorizontal;
```

For Diagonal Crosshatch:

```
ws.Cells["D1:D" + lastRowNumber].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.LightTrellis;
```

Comment: yes that's what I figured out as well, after trying different settings. Its a pity they don't have a detailed documentation, Thanks though.